# How DisplayLink will be treated in Ubuntu 16.04 (fb ov display device?)

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, displaylink

I'm trying to hookup 3 external monitors (3 * 1920* 1080) to my Dell XPS 15 (9550).

I thought that it will go with Matrox TrippleHead2Go DP edition by means of Thunderbolt port.

No way - Matrox is able to provide me with 5760 * 1080 "screen", but is is seen as Display device (creen) and not a Video card (/dev/fbX). My Intel and Nvidia (!) cards are not able to do more then 3840 * 2160 digital resolution. So I used 2 monitors with Matrox and have to find a way to hookup another one.

The issue here is that TrippleHead2Go is seen form Ubuntu as a Display, not a video card (fb device). So as this large screen get's attached to internal card as a DisplayPort transported over Thunderbolt, neither Nvidia, nor Intel are capable to handle it. So the only way to have 3* 1920 is to introduce additional video card to the system (/dev/fb1).

I knew that there are USB3 DisplayLink enabled adapters, but in my case the question is:

**Will Ubuntu 16.04 treat DisplayLink as a video card or as a display?**

I found out *lsusb* output, but could not find any info regarding the way system is treating the adapter. I saw some notes regarding /dev/fb1, but am not sure.

P.S. I am aware of so called Graphic boxes - an external device with PCIe and Thunderbolt connection where you can place additional video card of your choice. But I am not sure I really want to go that way even as it is most correct one in therms of performance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware.

Comment: well, we can close it, but where than if not here I can find information? This question is actually targeting users that do use DisplayLink devices

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So basically the answer is simple: it depends on the hardware on the other end of DisplayLink cable.

*If device being attached to DisplayLink port identify itself as a display, than Linux will treat it as a display (physical monitor device to be precise).*

*If device being attached to DisplayLink port identify itself as a Video card than Linux will treat it as a video processing hardware.*

There are many thing that can be attached to DisplayLink and in such case DL will play only a transport role.

What about my own question:
Matrox TrippleHead2Go DP edition present itself as a display device (monitor). Configurable firmware in the appliance will define resolution of such a "virtual" device for Linux on one hand and will split image across several physical monitors to match such presentation on another.